# MATLAB: line specification marker size

Tags: matlab

When plotting multiple data series using both line specification (`X`,`Y`,`linespec`) triplets and (`PropertyName`,`PropertyValue`) doublets, only a single `MarkerSize` can be specified and this size applies to all data series. For instance,

```
plot(X1,Y1,'.b',X2,Y2,'-r','MarkerSize',5)
```

Is it possible to specify a different `MarkerSize` for each of the different data series without resorting to plotting the data series separately or subsequently altering plot handle properties? Neither of the following two commands is valid, but they give an idea of the desired result:

```
plot(X1,Y1,'.b',X2,Y2,'-r','MarkerSize',[5 10])
plot(X1,Y1,'.b','MarkerSize',5,X2,Y2,'-r','MarkerSize',10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
h = plot(X1,Y1,'.b',X2,Y2,'*r');
set(h(1),'MarkerSize',5);
set(h(2),'MarkerSize',2);
```

Comment: Thanks jonnat. That will work. Do you think it is impossible to specify everything in a single line? Cheers.

Comment: I don't know of a straightforward way to do it. I'd be interested to hear if someone knows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scatter`. It has the `SizeData` property which is a vector.

```
x = rand(10,1);
y = rand(10,1);
s = scatter(x,y);
set(s,'SizeData',linspace(1,100,10))
```

If you want to use line plot with markers, you can draw your plot, use `hold on`, and then draw `scatter` on top of it.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey. I would like to be able to choose different lineseries properties for each of my different data series, which `plot` permits but `scatter` unfortunately does not. For instance, `x=1:5; y=6:10; z=11:15; h=plot(x,x,'ok',y,y,'or',z,z,'ob'); set(h,'SizeData',[10 50 90])` would be nice, but there is no `SizeData` property for `plot`. This would, ideally, apply size `10` to `x` data, `50` to `y` data, and `90` to `z` data.

Answer (score 0):

For that it is probably

```
plot(x1,0,'+','MarkerSize',10)
```

Or any other plot within the loop just

```
plot(x?, 0, '+', 'MarkerSize', 10, 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'r')
```

Comment: Found this from another solution